# Is there a JUNIT annotation to skip after method for one test method?

Tags: java, junit, annotations

I've 5 test methods in a test class annotated with `@Test`.
I've `@Before` and `@After` methods too. Is there a way to skip the method with `@After` only for the first Test method and run it for the rest?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by skipping the `@After` method?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't skip the execution of a method marked with @After. You should probably think twice before doing it for test readability. However, if you really, really want to do it you could add a `boolean runAfter` field to your test class and set it to `false` in the first method. Furthermore, in the `@After` method add `if (runAfter) { /* after code here */ }`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped. Also need to know when I run couple of tests, the first test always takes a lot more time to get executed when compared to other test methods. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Mocking frameworks such as Mockito takes a few hundred milliseconds to start the first time it is used ni an execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you want it to be a bit universal, set a variable "afterToBeLaunched" to false in the @Before. And in the every test that needs @After, set it to true. Of course check it at the start of @After and if it is false, `return` the method.
2. If you use JUnit after 4.7 version, use @Rules. ( [Apply '@Rule' after each '@Test' and before each '@After' in JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078982/rule-applies-to-before-after-in-junit) ) You can use Rule instead of @After and using [TestName](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/TestName.html), you can read the name of the test there and do finishing actions according to the currently ending test.

Answer (score 3):

This question was asked a while ago, but with version 5 of JUnit (JUnit Jupiter), we can use `@Tag` and `TestInfo` to accomplish the same thing.  The idea is to add a tag to the test(s) that do not need to have `@AfterEach` executed and use `TestInfo` to determine if the current test contains that tag.  In code, this might look something like

```
class TestSuite {
    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        System.out.println("BeforeEach");
        // Set-up logic.
    }

    @AfterEach
    void afterEach(TestInfo testInfo) {
        if(testInfo.getTags().contains("SkipCleanup")) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("AfterEach");

        // Perform cleanup logic.
    }

    @Test
    @Tag("SkipCleanup")
    void myTestWithoutCleanup() {
        System.out.println("First Test");
        // Test logic.
    }

    @Test
    void myTestWithCleanup() {
        System.out.println("Second Test");
        // Test logic.
    }

    @Test
    void myOtherTestWithCleanup() {
        System.out.println("Third Test");
        // Test logic.
    }
}
```

The output for the above would look like

> BeforeEach
>
> First Test
>
> BeforeEach
>
> Second Test
>
> AfterEach
>
> BeforeEach
>
> Third Test
>
> AfterEach