# evaulate method of Statement executes before and test methods together

Tags: java, junit, annotations

I was trying to understand evaluate() method of Statement class say for example as per the code present in [Apply '@Rule' after each '@Test' and before each '@After' in JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078982/rule-applies-to-before-after-in-junit)

The evaluate method actually executes both before and after and then moves ahead.

```
                @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                System.out.println("I am Rule1");
                arg0.evaluate();
                System.out.println("I am Rule2");

                }
```

The part of the result of the above code is :

```
I am Rule1
I am before
I am Test1
I am Rule2
```

So, after "I am Rule1", how does "I am before" and "I am Test1" get displayed when at evaluate method?

Comment: post a complete working code.

Comment: The complete code is present in another question given above : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078982/rule-applies-to-before-after-in-junit

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc of the `@Rule` annotation:

> The Statement passed to the TestRule will run any Before methods, then the Test method, and finally any After methods

I.e., when you call the `evalute()` method on the Statement, the above happens. The code you surround the `evaluate()` call with is called before and after, respectively, the `Statement`-related stuff.

Comment: Thanks. So, does @Rule run only for test methods?

Comment: Yes, it only runs for test methods.