# Run a TestWatcher before the @After

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I wanted to take a screenshot when a test fails, but, afterwords, run the @After method.

Is it possible to do so? With TestWatcher the method failed() runs after the @After.

Furthermore, I cannot pass the @After content to the TestWatcher finished() because I have a super.afterTest() to call in @After.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found this blog post https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/understaning-junit-method-order-execution/ extremely helpful in understanding JUnit method execution orders.

Answer (score 2):

**It's impossible for `TestWacher` methods `finished()` or `failed()` to run before the `@after` method** given that `TestWatcher` is a base class for `Rules`.

Because of the way that rules are set up, you can't have a rule that comes after `@before` or before `@after`. You can think of rules like shells that you put on the test method. The first shell to go on is `@before/@after`. Thereafter the `@rules` are applied. (Reference @Troy in [Apply '@Rule' after each '@Test' and before each '@After' in JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078982/apply-rule-after-each-test-and-before-each-after-in-junit))

The execution order, for one `@test`, is as follows

```
@TestWatcher starting
@Before 
@Test
@After
@TestWatcher finished
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and changed my code to run the code from @After in the finished() method of a new Rule. So the order of execution is now:

- @After
- failed() (if failed)
- finished()