# Selenium+junit - Conflict with a @Rule and an @After method

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I'm working on automating some tests at work and want to add the ability to take a screenshot in case of a failed test. I know this can easily be done in a clean way with TestNG but all of our unit/integration tests are using jUnit so I'll have to stick to that.

I have the logic/code for it almost ready and it's working but I'm running into a conflict because the @Rule is executed after the @After tearDown() method and by that time the webDriver doesn't exist anymore so it doesn't have anything to take the screenshot from.

Here's my code:

```
  @Rule
  public TestRule testWatcher = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
      File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
      String scrFilename = "Screenshot_"+ DateUtils.now().getTime()+".png";
      File outputFile = new File(screenshotPath, scrFilename);
      try {
        LOGGER.info("Saving screenshot of failed test...");
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, outputFile);
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        LOGGER.warn("Error taking screenshot");
      }
    }
  };
```

And this is the tearDown method:

```
  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    LOGGER.info("Quitting browser");
    driver.quit();

    LOGGER.info("Stopping Chrome Driver Service");
    chromeDriverService.stop();
  }
```

The error I'm getting as it is now is this:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Session ID is
>   null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?

Which is of course what's happening. It's trying to call the code to take a screenshot after calling `driver.quit()` and `chromeDriverService.stop()`. If I comment those 2 lines then the screenshot is correctly saved.

What would be the proper way to handle this? Is there any way I can set it so the @Rule runs first then the @After?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, browsing/searching around a bit more I found [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078982/apply-rule-after-each-test-and-before-each-after-in-junit) which answers exactly what I wanted. What I did was add the tearDown code into the @Rule then call it with a `finally` after the `try/catch` block.

```
  @Rule
  public TestRule testWatcher = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
      File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
      String scrFilename = "Screenshot_"+ DateUtils.now().getTime()+".png";
      File outputFile = new File(screenshotPath, scrFilename);
      try {
        LOGGER.info("Saving screenshot of failed test...");
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, outputFile);
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        LOGGER.warn("Error taking screenshot");
      } finally {
        tearDown();
      }
    }

    public void tearDown() {
      LOGGER.info("Quitting browser");
      driver.quit();

      LOGGER.info("Stopping Chrome Driver Service");
      chromeDriverService.stop();
    }
  };
```